# File rename tool with list input and editing capabilities

Tags: windows, file-management, filenames

I'm looking for a file rename utility not dissimilar to [Ant](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/ant_renamer_portable).

Ant has two features I need:

1. Rename a set of files according to data in a text file/list
2. Insert string at position X in those file names

I would like to combine these features and insert a string at position X of a file name but have that string come from a list.

Windows 10, preferably free.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/).

I've used it for years and it supports both the features you are looking for and many more, such as regular expressions, undo renames, save configurations etc. It doesn't look pretty, but makes up for it in speed and functionality.

It supports Windows 10 and is free!

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and report back